# Is high blood pressure ever a symptom attributable solely to dehydration?

Tags: hypertension, dehydration

In other words, if someone doesn't have hypertension and they become dehydrated does, or can dehydration (not radical dehydration, just poor hydration practices) in and of itself cause high blood pressure? IE: Where once you are hydrated, all is well again?

I have read that it is implicated in rapid pulse in many cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dehydration](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2343381/) usually would result in hypotension (low blood pressure) and reflex tachycardia (rapid pulse) due to decreased circulating blood volume.  But depending on several factors, including the sympathetic reflex, transient elevated blood pressure might be seen.

However, hypertension is not diagnosed based on a single value, but repeated elevated values over time.  It is a different pathology than a temporary sympathetic reflex, and generally this is not fixed by rehydration.

Good hydration is an important part of good dietary practices that are the foundation for treatment of hypertension. However, diuretics (which reduce fluids) are also often used to treat hypertension.  There is a complex fluid balance involved, and it depends on a lot of factors.

***For any individual's application of these topics, see a physician.***

Good resources:

- [Nisha Charkoudian, John R Halliwill, Barbara J Morgan, John H Eisenach, and Michael J Joyner: "Influences of hydration on post-exercise cardiovascular control in humans"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2343381/), J Physiol. 2003 Oct 15; 552(Pt 2): 635–644. Published online 2003 Aug 8. doi: 10.1113/jphysiol.2003.048629 PMCID: PMC2343381, PMID: 14561843
- [American Heart Association: "Low Blood Pressure - When Blood Pressure Is Too Low", 2009.](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/high-blood-pressure/the-facts-about-high-blood-pressure/low-blood-pressure-when-blood-pressure-is-too-low)